# Php function doesn't run

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie

below is my HTML PHP form

```
<div id="user">
<form name="booksInput" action="theGamer.php" method="post">
<p>This Section is to add new USer Record in DB</p>
User F Name: <input type="text" name="Fuser">
User L Name: <input type="text" name="Luser">
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","library");
mysql_select_db("library",$con);
$sqlb = "SELECT * FROM books";
$queryb = mysql_query($sqlb);
while ($resultsb[] = mysql_fetch_object ( $queryb ));
?>
Book Name:<select name="bID">
<?php foreach ( $resultsb as $optionb ) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $optionb->bID; ?>"><?php echo $optionb->book;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select><br>
<?php               
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","library");
mysql_select_db("library",$con);
$sqlc = "SELECT * FROM country";
$queryc = mysql_query($sqlc);
while ( $resultsc[] = mysql_fetch_object ( $queryc ) );
array_pop($resultsc);
?>
Country Name:<select name="cID">
<?php foreach ( $resultsc as $optionc ) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo $optionc->cID; ?>"><?php echo $optionc->country;?>/option

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subUser">
</form> 
    </div>
```

now when the submit button nameing `sunUser` is pressed `theGamer.php` is directed and code for `theGamer.php` is below

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","library");
function insertBook()
{
global $con;
mysql_select_db("library",$con);
$book=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['books']);
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','$book')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
}`
echo "1 record added";
}

function insertCountry()
{
global $con;
mysql_select_db("library",$con);
$country=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
$sql="INSERT into country (cID, country) VALUES ('','$country')";

if (mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
echo "1 record added";
}
else{die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));}

}

function insertUser()
{
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","library");
mysql_select_db("library",$con);
$Fuser=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Fuser']);
$Luser=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Luser']);
$bID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bID']);
$cID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cID']);
$sql="INSERT INTO user (userid, uFname,uLname, bID, CID ) VALUES  
    ('','$Fuser','$Luser','bID','cID')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
    }

   //Code for Knowing which button is pressed
  if(isset($_POST['subBooks']))
  {
  insertBook();
  } 
 if(isset($_POST['subCountry']))
 {
 insertCountry();
 }
if(isset($_POST['subUser']))
 {
 insertUser();
 } 
?>
```

it gives this error 
Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING` or `T_VARIABLE` or `T_NUM_STRING` in `C:\wamp\www\library\theGamer.php` on line 20 wheras the line number 20 have np concern about because the `subUser` button is pressed and the if statement must go to `u=insertuser` function why is it giving the error at line 20

Regards 
Ap

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**warning**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: And the reason of you `E_DOESNT_WORK` is explained in the error message.

Comment: Look at what the syntax highlighter of stackexchange has done to your code. This should give you a hint about what's wrong.

Comment: stackoverflow i have just started learning php dont make ppls to quit programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$book=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['books']);
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','$book')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
}`   <---  Here is a rogue quote..
```

The syntax highlighter if StackOverflow spotted this problem. Do you use an editor with a highlighter too?

Since the code is now invalid, PHP cannot parse the file and will fail. It doesn't matter that you don't actually execute this piece of code, because the whole file is parsed. This is different from runtime errors, which occur after the code is parsed and when the code is executing. In your case, the error occurs before any PHP code is executed at all.

Comment: thanx again for ur kind support